# SSIS: Defining a Generic Folder Connection String Per Control Flow

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, ssis

I've just built my first SSIS package. It has 8 different control flows for 8 different data sets (Excel workbooks). Currently, the source connection strings point at 8 dummy workbooks and will have to be changed manually as files populate to sub-folders which are based on the different sets of data. How do I create a generic connection string in each control flow that points at the 8 different folders which correspond to the different data sets in order to automate the file pointing?

Comment: Search on _SSIS expressions_ (this is how you set your connection manager dynamically ). Now search on _SSIS parameters_ (this is how you set your values at runtime). Someone is likely to describe a more complete solution and if not - I will

Comment: Declare a variable (string) in the outer most level. Then you can use a for each loop reading from a table, or parent folder and then use a generic data flow to process the files. Or set that variable at the start of each data flow, set the connection string of the flat file connection to that variable and then start procession.. Start at the following path for examples: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/